# Calling a function located in a parent user control from a child user control in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my parent form:

```
 public partial class ParentControl: UserControl
 {

    public ParentControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm child= new ChildForm ();
        child.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        TabPage tabNewChild= new TabPage("Child");
        tabNewChild.Controls.Add(child);

        tabDetails.TabPages.Add(tabNewChild);
        tabDetails.SelectedIndex = tabDetails.TabPages.IndexOf(tabNewChild);
    }
     void CloseTab()
     {
          \\Close the selected tab
     }
}
```

This is my child usercontrol:

```
public partial class ChildForm : UserControl
{
    public ChildForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         \\Call the CloseTab in parent user control.
    }
}
```

What is the optimal and proper way of implementing this?

I have researched about delegates and eventargs but cant decide what to use.

I have lots of modules that will be implemented in this way thats why I want to know the proper way of doing it. THanks a lot.

Comment: You can make the `CloseTab` public. Then in child control, check if the `Parent` is `ParentControl`, cast it to `ParentControl` and call its `CloseTab` method.

Comment: Raise your own event so the parent can subscribe it.  You need to bubble it since the parent knows nothing about ChildForm (bad name btw).  So event in ChildForm, subscribed by ParentControl.  And event in ParentControl so the real parent can subscribe it.

Comment: I would just declare it `protected`. Check [access modifiers documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to create an event on your user control that is triggered when a close is requested:

```
public partial class ChildForm : UserControl
{
    public ChildForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler CloseTabRequested;

    protected virtual void OnCloseTabRequested(EventArgs e)
    {
         CloseTabRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         OnCloseTabRequested(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

You can handle the event in the parent form:

```
 public partial class ParentControl: UserControl
 {

    public ParentControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm child= new ChildForm ();
        child.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        child.CloseTabRequested += ChildForm_CloseTabRequested;
        TabPage tabNewChild= new TabPage("Child");
        tabNewChild.Controls.Add(child);

        tabDetails.TabPages.Add(tabNewChild);
        tabDetails.SelectedIndex = tabDetails.TabPages.IndexOf(tabNewChild);
    }

    void ChildForm_CloseTabRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CloseTab((ChildForm)sender);
    }

    void CloseTab(ChildForm requestingForm)
    {
        \\Close the selected tab
    }
}
```

With this solution the user control is not bound to a specific parent form for maximum reusability. It also avoids a dependency of the child form on the parent form, which is good design.

Comment: Implementing it this way. How to I know which tab to close?

Comment: @Bigboss In the question you have asked about "*Close the selected tab*". However, to determine the child control which has requested for closure you can create your own custom event args having a property of type of child control. Then when raising the event in the child control, set `this` as value of that property. Then in he event handler in the parent control, you have access to the property of the event arg.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Not really well verse in winform yet. Can you show it to me? would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Bigboss You can define `public class CloseTabRequestedEventArgs: EventArgs  { public ChildForm Child {get; set;} }`, then define `public event EventHandler<CloseTabRequestedEventArgs> CloseTabRequested;` and then to raise it from an instance of child form this way: `CloseTabRequested?.Invoke(this, new CloseTabRequestedEventArgs(){ChildForm = this});`. It's the simplest implementation, however, in a better implementation, I'd make the property readonly and just set it in constructor. Also I'd use a protected virtual method to raise the event.

Comment: Really lost in the protected virtual method. Can you pls post an answer? ill just marked it as the correct after.

Comment: Posted answers are good enough for this question and I'd rather to not post another answer. Follow the simplest implementation and leave the enhancements for later. Just remember, if you decided to use this answer + my comments, then the signature of the event handler should be `void ChildForm_CloseTabRequested(object sender, CloseTabRequestedEventArgs e)` and `e.Child` is the requested child.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Added the `OnCloseTabRequested` method to follow the common practice. A separate event arguments class is unnecessary. The event consumer can evaluate the `sender`.

Comment: Yes, since the child control raises the event, relying on sender is acceptable. If there is a possibility for the parent control to raise a similar event then the separate event arg makes more sense. (Something like `Click` event of `ToolStripItem` and `ItemClicked` event of `ToolStrip`).

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the Parent property of the ChildForm then cast it to ParentControl and call the CloseTab method:

```
public partial class ChildForm : UserControl
{
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    (Parent as ParentControl)?.CloseTab(this);
  }
}
```

You may add the tab instance as method argument to close the good tab.

```
public partial class ParentControl: UserControl
{
  public void CloseTab(ChildForm sender)
  {
    // close sender
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that `Parent` sometimes needs to be set, before use

Comment: How do I know which tab to close?

Comment: @Bigboss Pay attention to the `sender` parameter which is added by Olivier.

Comment: This one is i think close tied up with each other and wont be able to have many child forms.

Comment: CloseTab is never executed. Already set the child.Parent = this.

Comment: I see. It is normal. I did not see that. It is because your system is bad designed. You insert control in a tab, so the parent of the control is the tab. It can't be the ParentControl. When you add the childcontrol in the tab, the parent is the tab... You can't have two parents else the control is not visible. The names of the controls you create are confusing too. What do you want to do exactly? Have you an image of your goal? You should update the question to tell what you do from the point of view of a final form presented to the user. What is the UX?